# How to create a table from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

The following is the dataframe I have

```
col1<-c(1960,1960,1965,1986,1960
        ,1969,1960,1993,1983,1924,
        1960,1993,1960,1972
        ,1960,1969)
col2<-c ("a", "c","a","b", "a", "c",
         "b","a", "b","a", "b", "a", 
          "c","c","a","a" )
mydata<-data.frame(col1,col2)
```

I want to create a two-way table that calculate the proportion for each category (a, b and c) respectively before 1970 and  after 1970 .

The desired output should be:

```
year            a       b        c
before 1970     0.545   0.181    0.272
after 1970      0.4     0.4      0.2
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Thank you @RichardScriven, but it seems it doesn't completely reach to the desired result. For the outcome, I want the first column to be year, before 1970 and after 1970, but the the syntax you recomended offer a logical value FALSE  and TRUE. Would you have a further idea to change a little bit more to get to the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `transform` the dataset to create another column with `after 1970` and `before 1970` values.  This can be done by first creating a logical vector (`col1 <= 1970`), adding 1 to it so that `TRUE` becomes 2 and `FALSE` as 1.  Use that as numeric index to change the values to `after 1970` and `before 1970`.  Then, we get the frequency of the subset of columns ('col2' and 'col3') with `table`.  Finally, the proportion by row can be got with `prop.table` with `MARGIN` specified as 1.

```
prop.table(table(transform(mydata, col3=c("after 1970", 
          "before 1970")[(col1<=1970)+1L])[3:2]), 1)
#                col2
# col3                  a         b         c
#   after 1970  0.4000000 0.4000000 0.2000000
#   before 1970 0.5454545 0.1818182 0.2727273
```

---

Or another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
#convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydata)`)
#create the "year" column based on 'col1' values
setDT(mydata)[col1<=1970, year:= "before 1970"
                 ][is.na(year), year:= "after 1970"]
#we can use `dcast` to change from long to wide format
dcast(mydata, year~col2, length)[, .SD/sum(unlist(.SD)) , year]
#          year         a         b         c
 #1:  after 1970 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.2000000
 #2: before 1970 0.5454545 0.1818182 0.2727273
```

---

Or with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
   mutate(year= ifelse(col1 <= 1970, "before 1970", "after 1970")) %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   mutate(n1=n()) %>%
   group_by(col2,n1, add=TRUE) %>% 
   tally() %>% 
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(n=n/n1) %>%
   select(-n1) %>% 
   spread(col2,n)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, it perfectly works. but I am not very understand the logic of the final part  **[(col1<=1970)+1L])[3:2]), 1)**, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @eclo.qh The `col1 <= 1970` gives a logical vector of `TRUE/FALSE`.  When we add 1 to it , `TRUE` values will become 2 and `FALSE` as 0.  THe default integer representation is 1/0.  This can be used an index to change those elements to `after 1970` and `before 1970`

Comment: sorry for late response @arkun , but I am still confused with the code.  I am a R bigginer, so the function is very new for me. I am not very clear with the usage of bracket `[(col1<=1970)+1])[3:2]` , I know that `transform ()` function create a new column to the data frame, which is `col3`, but I don't understand this statement **a logical vector (col1 <= 1970), adding 1 to it so that TRUE becomes 2 and FALSE as 1, Use that as numeric index to change the values to after 1970 and before 1970.** , Does the index 1 and 2 mean first row and second row created in new table?

Comment: Hi, @akrun. I split the code and run it step by step, and now I understand more. The index 2 and 1 represent `after 1970` and `before 1970`. The final question is that does `[3:2]` mean that  setting column 3 in the old dataframe as the row of the new table and column 2 as the column of the new table?

Comment: @eclo.qh It is just to flip the columns 3 to 1st postion and 2 to 2nd position for the `table`.  You can check by using `[2:3]` and the result you get.

Comment: @eclo.qh To understand it better, just do this `v1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE); v2 <- v1+1L; c("No", "Yes")[v2]`

Answer (score 2):

I generally find that one should `round` the results of prop.table:

```
> with( mydata, round( prop.table(table(col1 <= 1970, col2)), 3))
       col2
            a     b     c
  FALSE 0.125 0.125 0.062
  TRUE  0.375 0.125 0.188
```

If you label table dimensions, you may want to quote some of hte names if they have operators in them:

```
with( mydata, round( prop.table(table(`Year<=1970` = (col1 <= 1970), Column_2=col2)), 3))
          Column_2
Year<=1970     a     b     c
     FALSE 0.125 0.125 0.062
     TRUE  0.375 0.125 0.188
```

Fixing the semantic error of labeling FALSE as "1970 or before":  If you what to modify the row and column names then use `dimnames<-`. First assign that result to an object, 'temp', then:

```
> dimnames(temp)[[1]] <- list('after 1970', '1970 or before')
> temp
                Column_2
Year<=1970           a     b     c
  after 1970     0.125 0.125 0.062
  1970 or before 0.375 0.125 0.188
```

`prop.table` lets one deliver row or column proportions if the MARGIN is specified. Here we use `margin=1` for row-margins (and will swap rows with an index-reversal before the name change):

```
tb2 <- with( mydata, round( 
     prop.table(table(`Period` = (col1 <= 1970), Column_2=col2), margin=1), 3))[2:1, ]
dimnames(tb2)[[1]] <- list('1970 or before', 'after 1970')
tb2
                Column_2
Period               a     b     c
  1970 or before 0.545 0.182 0.273
  after 1970     0.400 0.400 0.200
```

The other useful function often used in the sort of operation is `addmargins` which will add the row and/or the column totals to a table of counts or values (but obviously not very interesting once these have been converted to proportions.)

Comment: Thanks @42-, but it seems the proportion in the cell is not correct.

Comment: I did wonder about the difference in our answers. If you would have specified that you wanted row proportions, then my cluelessness might not have been so exposed. It's fairly easy to give that as a result.

Comment: Thanks@42-, my apology to foget mentioning about that.

Comment: And now I'm noticing that I gave the wrong labels to the rows.